# Highcharts. How to remove svg stroke around chart container?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Have a problem with highcharts, when i do drillup on pie chart around the chart's container some border appears.[image]

According to my investigation, it's not a css style, but **stroke** attribute of the SVG element. It's not a **borderWidth** property of chart config, because it adds a new border near existing one. And i didn't find how to disable it, all of the advices were related to disabling stroke on individual chart series, but not the container like in my case.
Would appreciate any advice)

Comment: Can you share the highcharts settings for the graph?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor that I could work on?